# An Extension of "Using Variations of 'Apply' in R"

Tags: r, categorical-data

I asked the question earlier here [Using variations of `apply` in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730342/using-variations-of-apply-in-r). Now I have an extension to that question. In my 40 variables, some variables are categorical. I need the number of observations for each unique quality. I would like to use some form of `apply` because I have been using `sapply` and `tapply` on various parts of this code, but it is not required. Here is a bit of the data:

```
Age Wt  Ht  Type    Color   Width
79  134 66  C   red small
67  199 64  C   green   small
39  135 78  T   yellow  small
92  149 61  C   yellow  medium
33  138 75  T   green   medium
68  139 71  C   yellow  medium
95  198 62  T   red     large
65  132 65  T   blue    large
56  138 81  C   green   large
71  193 78  T   blue    large
```

What the last two columns should look like is

```
        C    T
 red    1    1
 green  2    1
 blue   0    2
 yellow 2    1
 small  2    1
 medium 2    1
 large  1    3
```

Also, I know I could use 'table', but how do I send multiple variables one at a time against *Type* in order to get it to look something like this? Using `table` as opposed to `apply` is fine with me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `table` after `unlist`ing the 'Color' and 'Width' columns and replicating the 'Type'.

```
Un1 <- unlist(df1[5:6])
Un2 <- df1$Type[row(df1[5:6])]
```

If we need a customer order, convert to `factor` and specify the `levels` in the same order.

```
table(factor(Un1, levels = c("red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "small",
                   "medium", "large")), Un2)
#   Un2
#         C T
#  red    1 1
#  green  2 1
#  blue   0 2
#  yellow 2 1
#  small  2 1
#  medium 2 1
#  large  1 3
```

Or if the `order` is based on the `order` of appearance of `unique` elements in each of the columns

```
table(factor(Un1, levels = unique(Un1)), Un2)
```

Comment: They end up out of order, though. I still need the _Colors_ together and the _Widths_ together. They actually end up alphabetized.

Comment: @akash87 Can youcheck now

Comment: It looks good, but I do have 15 variables like this, so listing all the levels is going to be a challenge. I was thinking about using `sapply(df[5:6], unique)` but that returns a matrix. Any more thoughts? And thanks for the help!

Comment: @akash87 Actually it would be `factor(Un1, levels = unique(Un1))`, but in your expected output, it is still a customer order (if your check `blue` comes before `yellow`)

Comment: @akash87 Can you update your expected output in the post as it is not clear.

Comment: I did not mean to unaccept the question. But yes you are right it is another question that I figured out the answer to anyways.